# syntax error with FOREIGN KEY in CREATE TABLE

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I am getting following output on debugger. I am not sure what syntax is missing.

The SQL code is:

```
CREATE TABLE weeks(Week_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Day TEXT, 
  Start_Time Text, 
  End_Time Text, 
  Break_Time Text );
CREATE TABLE projects(Project_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Name TEXT, 
  Description Text, 
  Client_Name Text, 
  Location Text );  
CREATE TABLE timesheets(Timesheet_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Project_Id  INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (Project_Id) REFERENCES projects (Project_Id),
  Week_Id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (Week_Id) REFERENCES weeks (Week_Id));
```

The error boils down to:

```
12-09 12:34:20.782: E/SQLiteLog(6490): (1) near "Week_Id": syntax error
```

Comment: It might be possible that your FOREIGN KEY declarations should be after your variable declarations. It's worth a shot...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try moving your `FOREIGN KEY` lists to after your variables are created.

```
CREATE TABLE timesheets(Timesheet_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Project_Id  INTEGER,
  Week_Id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (Project_Id) REFERENCES projects (Project_Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Week_Id) REFERENCES weeks (Week_Id));
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the SQLite syntax (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) you can also write something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE timesheets(Timesheet_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Project_Id  INTEGER REFERENCES projects (Project_Id),
Week_Id INTEGER REFERENCES weeks (Week_Id));
```

This merges declarations and foreign keys.

Comment: Only issue with this approach is it makes it difficult to migrate these tables to other SQL systems if you end up outgrowing SQLites capabilities.

Sticking with the standard `FOREIGN KEY` definitions would be recommended if there are plans to move to another SQL system in the future.